# Scrape a webpage and get images more than particular width and particular height using php

Tags: php, image, web-scraping

Am able to scrape the images from a website using php but I want to scrape the only first image that has height greater than 200px and width 200px. How can I get the dimensions of first image source? Here is my code..

```
 $html_3 = file_get_contents('http://beignindian.com');
 preg_match_all( '|<img.*?src=[\'"](.*?)[\'"].*?>|i',$html_3, $matches ); 
 $main_image_1 = $matches[ 1 ][ 0 ];
```

Comment: how do you know that it's greater than 200 width & height ?

Comment: by using get_image_size so the first image which satisfies the above I need its url if there is no image in that website like that then null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`getimagesize`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) function to get the image height and width. Once you get it then add if condition to execute further code.

```
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($main_image_1); // I am assuming that $main_image_1 has image source.
echo "width: " . $width . "<br />";
echo "height: " .  $height;
if($width > 200 && $height > 200) {

  // perform something here.

}
```

**Update:**

If you need to loop through all the images from a website then use following code:

```
$host = "http://www.beingindian.com/";

$html = file_get_contents($host);

// create new DOMDocument
$document = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');

// set error level
$internalErrors = libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

// load HTML
$document->loadHTML($html);

// Restore error level
libxml_use_internal_errors($internalErrors);


$images = $document->getElementsByTagName('img');

foreach ($images as $image) {
   $image_source = $image->getAttribute('src');

   // check if image URL is an absolute URL or relative URL
   $image_url = (filter_var($image_source, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL))?$image_source:$host.$image_source;

   list($width, $height) = getimagesize($image_url); 
   if($width > 200 && $height > 200) {
      // perform something here.
   }
   else {
      // perform something here.
   }
}
```

Comment: I need to crawl through all images in website not one

Comment: then you can use a loop and check the size of all of them :)

Comment: In the above how can I loop am unable to do it as don't how many images will be there in a wesite

Comment: @sravyanaidu : Check my updated answer. All the best!

Comment: thanks for information but am having one doubt as soon as I found the first image with width and height greater than 200px I need to stop it and store in a varibla

Comment: then you can add a `break;` statement in if condition to break the loop and to store it and use it later, you can use `$image_source` variable because it has image URL.

Comment: am getting error like this while running above one..Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity, line: 41 in C:\xampp\htdocs\62\example.php on line 5

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity, line: 41 in C:\xampp\htdocs\62\example.php on line 5

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Tag bi-header invalid in Entity, line: 90 in C:\xampp\htdocs\62\example.php on line 5

Comment: can you please check updated code posted in my answer?

Comment: Warning: Creating default object from empty value in C:\xampp\htdocs\62\example.php on line 15

Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::getElementsByTagName() in C:\xampp\htdocs\62\example.php on line 16

Comment: @sravyanaidu: Code is updated for you. Check it now. We are getting relative image links after scraping so I have also attached host name with image source and that should work fine for you. I hope you can manage minor changes yourself if you may more warnings.

Comment: yeah thank you but if there is already hostname in starting url how can I prevent it from adding

Comment: @sravyanaidu Check updated code! I don't know but you are so lazy to find something yourself ;)

Comment: There was one minor typing mistake in `$image_url`. Fixed now! And don't forget to upvote my answer if it worked for you! Cheers.

Comment: its also showing error assets/images/loader-animation.gif
Warning: getimagesize(http://www.beingindian.com/../assets/images/back-to-top-button.png): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request in C:\xampp\htdocs\62\example.php on line 28
assets/images/post-placeholder.png

Comment: Add `$image_source = str_replace("..","", $image_source);` after `$image_source = $image->getAttribute('src');`